# XElement.Remove (XNode.Remove) doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml, xelement

I'm trying to remove individual nodes from their parent, I tried the [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove.aspx) method but it doesn't seem to be working. How is this done? Is this a bug or what?

```
Sub Main()
  Dim xml =
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Products>
      <Product name="ABC-1" link="http://www.site.com/1"/>
      <Product name="ABC-2" link="http://www.site.com/2"/>
      <Product name="ABC-3" link="http://www.site.com/3"/>
    </Products>

  Dim products = xml.Root.<Product>

  'works - uncomment
  'products.Remove()

  'Doesn't work
  For Each product In products
    product.Remove()
  Next

  xml.Save(FailedFilename)
End Sub
```

Comment: There isn't any `Remove(T)` method in products? `products.Remove(product)`

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @JohnSaunders it means that the elements still exist under their parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the nodes while looping over `products` causes it to be modified. Since it's an `IEnumerable<XElement>` you need to avoid lazy evaluation in order to work on the entire result at once. To do so simply add a call to `ToArray()` or `ToList()`:

```
For Each product In products.ToArray()
    product.Remove()
Next
```

Note that the above is equivalent to the following snippet. It is not the same as adding `ToArray()` while declaring the `products` variable:

```
Dim temp = products.ToArray()
For Each product In temp
    product.Remove()
Next
```

The issue you're running into is nicely summarized on this MSDN page: [Mixed Declarative Code/Imperative Code Bugs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387088.aspx), specifically the section titled "Deleting While Iterating."

Unless you need to work with each `product` prior to removing it, the first approach of using the [`Remove` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554.aspx) is much simpler: `products.Remove()`.